# Connect Azure Hadoop HDInsight Cluster with Azure data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

[Error facing during connection in ADF pipeline]
I am facing issue while connecting Azure Hive db with Azure data factory.

[image]

Comment: is this persistent or transient?

Comment: this is persistent type @ZiyaMertKarakas